# How to make v/h distance equal within the figures?

Tags: floats, align

[image]

Hi, every one, do everyone learn how i can make the vertical and horizontal distance even(equal) the code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}   
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_1.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:a}    %
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \centering   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_2.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:b}   
  \end{minipage}   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \centering   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_3.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:c}   
  \end{minipage}   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \centering   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_4.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:d}   
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  It is not quite clear to me what you are asking.  However, beware of stray spaces between your `minipage`s.  Try replacing `\end{minipage}` by `\end{minipage}%` on each occurance.

Comment: Thanks, you see the vertical distance and horizontal distance between my four images are not the same, I just want to make the distances equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `minipage`s and `\label`s adds nothing. If your images have the same aspect ratio, you can use a couple of tricks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\twocolgraphwd}
\newenvironment{twocolgraphics}[1][1em]
 {%
  \centering
  \setlength{\twocolgraphwd}{\textwidth}% First step
  \addtolength{\twocolgraphwd}{-#1}% remove the space in between
  \setlength{\twocolgraphwd}{.5\twocolgraphwd}% divide by two
  \setlength{\lineskip}{#1}% set \lineskip to the same gap
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{\fill}% fill the space between “words”
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\twocolgraphwd}% all images have the same width
 }
 {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{twocolgraphics}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{twocolgraphics}

\caption{Four figures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{twocolgraphics}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{twocolgraphics}

\caption{Three figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you say `\begin{twocolgraphics}[2em]` the space would be doubled.

[image]

Comment: wow, it is solved perfectly. Much appreciated! May I ask you that I could not compile the \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}  is it because I have not installed the package correctly (the package manager shows it is uncategorized) ?

Comment: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `most' for package `tcolorbox

Comment: @Tony You probably have an outdated version

Comment: thanks a lot. It is ok now when I update all the packages

Comment: Dear egreg， when I use your method to add four pics in the beamer frame, the framse size seems to be too small to show all 4 pics, how can I scale the four pics in one slide to make them show completely. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony `\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{filename}`, perhaps.

Comment: yes actually only with \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{filename} can work fine, but here your code has already created a new environment (\newenvironment{twocolgraphics}[1][1em]), so further more adding the [width=0.4\textwidth] does not work, thanks

Comment: @Tony Sorry, but I don't understand. Since `beamer` is quite a different beast, perhaps it's better to ask a followup question.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its `raster` library. It arranges boxes or images in a matrix form which initially keeps same distance `(2mm)` between columns and rows although you can adjust with `raster column skip` and `raster row skip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcbraster}[enhanced,raster columns=2, size=tight]
\tcbincludegraphics[label=fig:side:a]{example-image-A}
\tcbincludegraphics[label=fig:side:a]{example-image-B}
\tcbincludegraphics[label=fig:side:a]{example-image-C}
\tcbincludegraphics[label=fig:side:a]{example-image}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i don't know why my tex cannot compile the code you provide in my computer. If I could keep the same distance (2mm) both for the column and row, that would be perfect

Comment: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `most' for package `tcolorbox

Comment: @Tony: Probably a typing mistake but the option is `most` and not `most'`. If you wrote it correctly, what `tcolorbox` version do you use?

Comment: @lgnasi: it is not a typing mistake,because i just copy your code, it also is unable to compile. My tcolorbox is based on a full version MTKtex 2.9 on the windows system

Comment: When did you update this version for the last time? Most recent update of miktex system and packages is from 22/03/2015. Last `tcolorbox` version is 3.50, but even with earlier versions `most` was a valid option.

Comment: @Tony Instead of `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` you can try with `\usepackage{tcolorbox} \tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}`.

Comment: @lgnasi I could not fix it, just now i update the 3.50 version by using the Upadate Miktex automatically, but it still dose not work, I am a beginer, so may have many questions, thanks you very much for showing me so much!

Comment: @lgnasi, when I update all the packages, it works fine now. Thanks again

Comment: hi, may I ask you a follow-up question, it works well to create four pics with even skips in the article, but when it comes to the the beamer frame, the flame could not show all the four pics completely in one slide by using the code \begin{tcbraster}[enhanced,raster columns=2, size=tight], and when I add a scale=0.8, the {tcbraster}[enhanced,raster columns=2, scale=0.8, size=tight],the four figs can show completely, but they can not locate in the center of the slide? Could you show me how to solve this? Much thanks. 
@lgnasi

Comment: @Toni, you can ask as many as follow-up questions you want. But it's better do it like new questions making reference to the originals. Take a look at tcolorbox manual and look there for `raster width` and `raster halign`. You must remember that `beamer`size is smaller than a4paper or letter.

Comment: thanks for your reminding and advices, as a new beginner, I need some more time to acquire the numerous packages. Exactly the beamer size is smaller than the a4 paper, but I do not know to solve it yet

Comment: raster width=0.8\textwidth, raster halign=center, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

add horizontal space with \hspace* and you don't need centering

```
\begin{figure}   
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_1.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:a}    %
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace*{\baselineskip}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_2.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:b}   
  \end{minipage}   
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_3.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:c}   
  \end{minipage}  
  \hspace*{\baselineskip} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}   
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_4.jpg}   
    \label{fig:side:d}   
  \end{minipage} 
\end{figure}
```